# JavaScript Jquery dynamic OOP call

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

Ok, not sure if I am going to give myself any justice in trying to describe this. But..

I have an some code OOP style where you would call it like: `objectName.functionName(properties, values, etc);`

and as of the moment I seem to have reached a road block. I am multiple functions that do various things, but I have this one function that I want to act as a "Refresh" function for the many. Which would work if it was a single function I wanted to refresh from time to time. Overall i don't wish to reinvent the wheel either.

So my current click event looks like a call to the above. Where in the link I am using I have my hidden parameters per the needs of the functions which this works, fine But heres the catch 22 I recently ran into a need to have multiple refreshes on the same page for various functions. So I am wondering is there a way I can pass functionName as a variable to the object so it would work like

```
var funcNamVar = functionName; 
objectName.[funcNamVar](properties, values, etc);
```

note the brackets [ and ] are just for representation of the concept I know they shouldnt be there

Comment: The brackets are actually the way to go :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.  You can actually just do

```
objectName[funcNamVar](properties, values, etc);
```

Comment: ha, that . got me, very cool.. good to have it confirmed, thank you.

Comment: Yeah, and make sure funcNameVar is a string literal. E.g. `foo` is a string literal if `var foo = "bar"`